# Parameterized Query: Check if field is in array of values in SELECT statement

Tags: java, sql, postgresql, jdbc, parameterized

I'm trying to configure a parameterized query to the effect of:

```
SELECT field1 FROM myTable WHERE field2 IN (1,2,3,4)
```

The database I'm using is Postgres.

This query run successfully unparameterized, but I'd like to use a parameterized query with a JdbcTemplate to fill in the list for valid field2 values (which are integers).

Trying various values for `var` (`"1,2,3,4"`, `"[1,2,3,4]"`, `"{1,2,3,4}"`, or `"(1,2,3,4)"`) I've tried variations on the query:

```
myJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT field1 FROM field2 IN (?)", new Object[]{ var })
```

and

```
myJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT field1 FROM field2 IN (?::integer[])", new Object[]{ var })
```

and also

```
myJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT field1 FROM field2 IN ?::integer[]", new Object[]{ var })
```

On a side note, resources that describe how to parameterize queries would also be really helpful.

All of these queries throw PSQLExceptions that indicate the operator fails or that there's a type mismatch -- which seems reasonable as I can't figure out how to parameterize the query.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Take a look at the Spring [Data Access web page](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/jdbc.html), particularly section [11.7.3](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/jdbc.html#jdbc-in-clause) where using the [NamedParameterJdbcTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/namedparam/NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.html) to build an 'IN' clause is covered.

e.g.

```
NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate = new NamedParameterJdbcTemplate(dataSource);
String sql = "select * from emp where empno in (:ids)";
List idList = new ArrayList(2);
idList.add(new Long(7782));
idList.add(new Long(7788));
Map parameters = new HashMap();
parameters.put("ids", idList);
List emps = jdbcTemplate.query(sql, parameters, new EmpMapper());
```

Answer (score 2):

I took another look at the manual, it looks like to [search arrays](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/arrays.html) there's an alternative syntax, something like:

```
SELECT field1 FROM myTable WHERE field2 = ANY(ARRAY[1,2,3,4])
```

Which can be parameterized as:

```
myJdbcTemplate.query("SELECT field1 FROM myTable WHERE field2 = ANY(?::integer[])"), new Object[]{ "{1,2,3,4}" })
```